# Mostra valor hexadecimal no cmd.exe

Tags: c++, cmd, hexadecimal

Estou tentando mostrar a letra acentuada 'é' no `cmd.exe` através do hexadecimal, mas o `printf()` apenas mostra o valor do caractere em si.

Estou tentando o seguinte:

```
unsigned char eh = 0x82;
printf("%x", eh)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O printf está mostrando hexadecimal, pois você usou "%x", que é justamente isso! Mostrar o valor em hexadecimal :)

Basta usar desta forma, no caso do seu exemplo:

```
printf("%c" ,eh);
```

Lembrando que em C++11 você pode usar UTF-8 direto no código:

```
char* acentuada = u8"Acentuação";
printf("%s", acentuada);
```

É importante neste segundo se assegurar que seu editor de código esteja configurado para UTF-8.

> Lembre-se que nos dois casos, a forma que seu ambiente está configurado (página de código, padrão de encoding) podem afetar a saída, mesmo que a entrada  e o código estejam certos.

De curiosidade eis os formatos principais do printf:

```
d ou i  Inteiro decimal com sinal                         392
u       Inteiro decimal sem sinal                        7235
o       Octal sem sinal                                   610
x       Inteiro hexadecimal sem sinal                     7fa
f       Ponto flutuante decimal                        392.65
e       Notação científica                          3.9265e+2
g       %e ou %f automático (o que for mais curto)     392.65
c       Caractere                                           b
s       Cadeia (string) de caracteres                   teste
p       Endereço de ponteiro                         ba000000
```

Notar que vários formatos que retornam letras, como `x` e `e`, por exemplo, podem ser escritos como `X` e `E` caso você queira a saída em maíusculas, como 7FA e 3.9265E+2.

Comment: Creio que deveria ser printf("%c" ,eh); já que a variável eh não é uma string e sim um caractere.

Comment: @Osvaldo na verdade adaptei pra strings mais extensas, como no caso do u8"...", de qualquer forma, foi bom comentar. Se for o caso, separo os dois exemplos pra nao confundir ninguém.

Comment: No caso do C++11, isso é problemático por que, embora o código de fato gere output em UTF-8, o CMD dificilmente estará configurado para reconhecer esse formato. Ele tem toda uma forma não standard de ser...

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal é, até tinha posto a nota em amarelo pensando nisso. Na verdade mesmo no exemplo original, a página de codigo vai variar muito de ambiente pra ambiente (e versão do sistema).

Comment: Muito obrigado, tinha me confundido um pouco mas agora entendi certo, resposta muito bem formulada! e vlw pela dica do UTF-8, mas @bacco, meu editor deve usar UTF-8 ou UTF-8 sem BOM?

Comment: @OlimonF geralmente os compiladores não gostam do BOM. BOM faz mais sentido em UTF16. Lembre-se que isso é só pra usar o u8"...., pois se for colocar os caracteres em hexa, o editor não importa. Olhe o comment do Guilherme também, o CMD normalmente não respeita UTF, mesmo que o código esteja certo.

Answer (score 4):

O correto é utilizar o `%c` para exibir o caractere, `%s` é usado para exibir uma cadeia de *strings*.

```
unsigned char eh = 0x82;
printf("%c", eh);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]