# Tabuada do 6, oq estou errando? LINGUAGEM C

Tags: c

Não está dando os resultados, sempre dá 0

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main ()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
 int i; 
 for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {
  printf("6 X %.0f = %.0f\n",i, 6*i);
 }
 return 0;
 system("pause");

}
```

Comment: o que está  você está vendo acontecer de errado ? o que você queria que acontecesse e não está acontecendo ?

Comment: n, está dando o resultado em todas 0 :/

Comment: Wesley, poderia comentar o objetivo desse `%.0f` do seu código e como chegou nisso?

Comment: %.0f ou uso pra mostrar onde terá uma variavel, ai depois eu coloco as variaveis e cada uma variavel vai para um lugar definido. se tiver duas variaveis, a primeira vai no primeiro %.0f e a segunda no segundo %.0f

Comment: Então, meu professor que falou pra usar isso kkkk

Comment: Duvido um pouco que ele tenha falado isso, provavelmente sua interpretação foi superficial - apesar de hoje em dia não duvidar de nada em relação a professores. - De qualquer forma, você deve usar a documentação da linguagem como base, e não "achar" nada.

Comment: Duvido menos que o Bacco, mas também duvido :) Ao menos não neste contexto acho que ele não falou exatamente isto.

Comment: Vcs poderiam me explicar em que contexto usasse o "%.0f"?

Comment: O bom mesmo seria ler a documentação. Veja esta resposta aqui, pode ajudar a entender sobre os placeholders da família do printf: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10880/70

Comment: Esse professor é complicado... Não explica quase nada, a gente que tem que ficar procurando soluções

Comment: Muito obrigado :) bom domingo

Comment: Agora percebi que o professor é ótimo, ele manda os alunos que vão trabalhar em uma profissão que é achar soluções o tempo todo fazer o que? Achar soluções! Queria que todos os professores fossem assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade é algo bem simples, teu erro ta no `printf` dentro do `for`, nele tu esta usando `%.0f` porém esta formatação é para `float` e o teu valor é `int`, então use o `%d`, veja rodando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/n0ByrE).

Comment: Ahhh, muito obrigado, não sabia que essa formatação era pra float

Comment: Um compilador decente teria emitido um warning a respeito disso

Comment: @epx, é verdade, possivelmente ele deve estar usando alguma versão desatualizada.